# android Google+ returns user birthday year as 0000

Tags: android, google-plus

I am using Google+ in my application for user login and posting on the user wall.

Posting on user wall works just fine.

But when i try to get user profile data it returns user birthday year as 0000.And this happens only for some user and for other user i get correct birthdate.

I have following code to initialize Google+ client

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(getApplicationContext(), this, this)
                    .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity").setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN, Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE).build();
```

and i have following code to retrieve user profile data:

```
mPlusClient.loadPerson(this, "me");
@Override
    public void onPersonLoaded(ConnectionResult arg0, Person arg1)
        {
            Log.i("Person",""+arg1.toString());

           if (currentperson.hasBirthday())
                            {
                                String Birthday = currentperson.getBirthday();
                                MyLog.i("Birthdate :", "" + Birthday);
                            }
            }
```

Why this is so?
Why it happens only for some users?
Am i missing something?

Please help me.

Comment: I don't know but I would guess its because those users either haven't submitted their birthday to Google+ or don't have it publicly available.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Users can decide in their profile settings, whether they want to have their birthday public (which are the only ones you will get) and an additional setting whether they want the year included as well. When this setting is disabled you will get `0000` as year instead of the real year.

[image: Birthday settings]